# TeeChart, "skip" rows value when column marked "Exclude"

Tags: delphi, teechart

Delphi XE3
Steema VCL Charting

I have a data source with 12 rows.  Each row has a vertical bar.  I have  a column in the table that is called Exclude.  If Exclude is True I do not want it to “draw” the bar for  that rows value.  How can I exclude some rows values from being charted programmatically?   The pseudo code would be…

If Exclude <> True then draw bar ;

If someone changes the Exclude value I want to redraw the graph to reflect the change in that rows value which means if Exclude is True the bar does not get drawn.

Comment: "Data source", "rows", "column", "table", ... - it's all about databases, how does it match to Chart terminology? If you loading data from database into the chart, then you probably can create SQL query to get all values from table but zeroes if corresponding values are in "exclude" table.

Comment: The problem is if I rerun the query excluding the rows where Exclude = True then the row would no longer be available to mark as False, restoring the bar.

Comment: You can load data to memory dataset (connected to chart) and keep/show them as long as you want without reloading from external storage (SQL server).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is using the *SetNull* method to make a bar null and hence not being painted, for example:

```
  if Exclude then Series1.SetNull(Index);
```

you can revert that calling *SetNull* like this:

```
  Series1.SetNull(Index, False);
```